# No Compilation Needed - Compile On Run

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Something weird that I've been seeing, a web application written in ASP.Net (C#) that got the source code on the production server and compile that way. So when I deploy to the server I deploy the source code.

Why does .Net have this functionality? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you sure that it is a "web application" project and not a "web site" project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already posted as a comment that I believe that this is a "Web Site" project and not a "Web Application" project, but I wanted to also add this link, which includes some nice links to comparisons of the two project types.

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is the way ASP.Net Web Sites work.

Notice that it's very similar to ASP classic, which ASP.Net superseded.

You can also deploy pre-compiled sites, if you want to.

Comment: How do I do the pre-compiled sites functionality?

Comment: You can create a web application project, or you can use the Publish wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Faster debugging cycle is my guess. For very large projects compiling everything takes time. If you're not interested in bleeding-edge performance (ie debugging a page or 2 over and over and over and over), you can choose not to recompile every time you make an adjustement.